# perfect forwarding failing for lvalues

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding, stdtuple

I have a utility function which iterates over a tuple, and for each element, calls a function with that element, and finally calls another function with the result of all the tuple elements.

To better illustrate:

- There is a tuple of various types `tuple<Foo<int>, Bar<double>, Baz<char>>`
- Each type `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` have an implicit interface `ClassT::data()` which returns a reference to some internal member `T&`.
- You have a function with the signature `void (int, double, char)`

The utility iterates over the tuple members, extracting the reference to the internal members, and calls the function with the required parameters.

#### Issue: perfect forwarding

I have tried to implement the utility using so-called "universal references" and perfect forwarding, thereby negating the need for multiple lvalue/rvalue and const/non-const overloads.

Whilst the parameter to the function is of type

```
template<typename Tuple>
auto invoke(Tuple&& tuple)
```

I cannot bind lvalues to it. Why is this?

I have asked a similar question leading up to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642087/generically-call-member-function-on-each-element-of-a-tuple) which has been solved; however since this is an unrelated issue, I believe this warrants a new question

Example on ideone: https://ideone.com/lO5JOB

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

// sequence

template<size_t...>
struct Sequence
{ };

template<size_t N, size_t... Seq>
struct GenerateSequence : GenerateSequence<N - 1, N - 1, Seq...>
{ };

template<size_t... Seq>
struct GenerateSequence<0, Seq...>
{
    using type = Sequence<Seq...>;
};

// invoke tuple

struct TupleForEachInvoker
{
    template<typename Func, typename ForEachFunc, typename Tuple, size_t... Seq>
    static auto invoke(Func&& func, ForEachFunc&& forEachFunc, Tuple&& tuple, Sequence<Seq...>)
        -> decltype(func(forEachFunc(std::get<Seq>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)))...))
    {
        return func(forEachFunc(std::get<Seq>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)))...);
    }

    template<typename Func, typename ForEachFunc, typename... Args>
    static auto apply(Func&& func, ForEachFunc&& forEachFunc, std::tuple<Args...>&& args)
        -> decltype(invoke(std::forward<Func>(func),
                           std::forward<ForEachFunc>(forEachFunc),
                           std::forward<std::tuple<Args...>>(args),
                           typename GenerateSequence<sizeof...(Args)>::type()))
    {
        return invoke(std::forward<Func>(func),
                      std::forward<ForEachFunc>(forEachFunc),
                      std::forward<std::tuple<Args...>>(args),
                      typename GenerateSequence<sizeof...(Args)>::type());
    }
};

template<typename Func, typename ForEachFunc, typename Tuple>
inline auto invokeWithMemberFromAll(Func&& func, ForEachFunc&& forEachFunc, Tuple&& tuple)
    -> decltype(TupleForEachInvoker::apply(std::forward<Func>(func),
                                           std::forward<ForEachFunc>(forEachFunc),
                                           std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)))
{
    return TupleForEachInvoker::apply(std::forward<Func>(func),
                                      std::forward<ForEachFunc>(forEachFunc),
                                      std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
}

// exemplar

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T& data() { return _val; }
    T _val;
};

struct Extract
{
    template<typename T>
    T& operator() (Foo<T>& f) { return f.data(); }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int>         i { 5 };
    Foo<double>      d { 6. };
    Foo<const char*> s { "hello world" };

    auto cb = [](int& i, const double& d, const char* s)
        {
            std::cout << "i=" << i << ", d=" << d << ", s=" << s << std::endl;

            i += 2;
        };


    // rvalue reference to tuple
    invokeWithMemberFromAll(cb, Extract{}, std::tie(i, d, s));

    std::cout << i.data() << std::endl;

    // lvalue reference to tuple - fails
    auto tuple = std::tie(i, d, s);
    invokeWithMemberFromAll(cb, Extract{}, tuple);

    std::cout << i.data() << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: [the one with the error](https://ideone.com/cMQDTj) is more useful than one without any errors.  :)

Comment: @Yakk - ha, fair enough - I'll update the question

Comment: Wow, what's with the down-vote? What exactly is so wrong with this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<typename Func, typename ForEachFunc, typename... Args>
static auto apply(Func&& func, ForEachFunc&& forEachFunc, std::tuple<Args...>&& args)
```

the 3rd argument is an rvalue `tuple`, not a tuple of forwarding references, or a forwarding reference to a tuple.

Universal references (currently called "forwarding references" in the under development C++1z standard) usually require a deduced type.  They do require that the type the `&&` is applied to could be either a reference or a non-reference type.  A `std::tuple<?>` is always a non-reference type, so `&&` makes it an rvalue reference, not a forwarding reference, when placed like `std::tuple<?>&&`.

It appears you switch from `Tuple&&` to `std::tuple<?>&&` for no reason other than to count the number of `Args...`.  If I'm right, then `std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>{}` equals `sizeof...(Args)`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `apply` function - it requires an `rvalue` of type `std::tuple<Args...>`:

```
template<typename Func, typename ForEachFunc, typename... Args>
    static auto apply(Func&& func, ForEachFunc&& forEachFunc, std::tuple<Args...>&& args)
```

Here's one possible fix using [`std::tuple_size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size) instead of `sizeof...(Args)` from your code:

```
struct TupleForEachInvoker
{
    template<typename Func, typename ForEachFunc, typename Tuple, size_t... Seq>
    static auto invoke(Func&& func, ForEachFunc&& forEachFunc, Tuple&& tuple, Sequence<Seq...>)
        -> decltype(func(forEachFunc(std::get<Seq>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)))...))
    {
        return func(forEachFunc(std::get<Seq>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)))...);
    }

    template<typename Func, typename ForEachFunc, typename Tuple>
    static auto apply(Func&& func, ForEachFunc&& forEachFunc, Tuple&& args)
        -> decltype(invoke(std::forward<Func>(func),
                           std::forward<ForEachFunc>(forEachFunc),
                           std::forward<Tuple>(args),
                           typename GenerateSequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>::type()))
    {
        return invoke(std::forward<Func>(func),
                      std::forward<ForEachFunc>(forEachFunc),
                      std::forward<Tuple>(args),
                      typename GenerateSequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>::type());
    }
};

template<typename Func, typename ForEachFunc, typename Tuple>
inline auto invokeWithMemberFromAll(Func&& func, ForEachFunc&& forEachFunc, Tuple&& tuple)
    -> decltype(TupleForEachInvoker::apply(std::forward<Func>(func),
                                           std::forward<ForEachFunc>(forEachFunc),
                                           std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)))
{
    return TupleForEachInvoker::apply(std::forward<Func>(func),
                                      std::forward<ForEachFunc>(forEachFunc),
                                      std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0d2ff7376417b10)