# Expanding a tuple with perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I needed to expand a tuple so that I can apply it's argument to a function. It was surprisingly easy to write.

```
template<template<class...> class Tup, class... Ts, class F>
decltype(auto) apply(F f, Tup<Ts...> &tup){
   return f(std::forward<Ts>(std::get<Ts>(tup))...);
}
```

And it can be used like this

```
auto it = std::make_tuple(1,2);
cout << apply([](int a, int b){return a + b;},it) << endl;
```

But what if I actually want to move the elements of the tuple into the function?

So I tried something more general

```
template<template<class...> class Tup, class... Ts, class F>
decltype(auto) apply(F f, Tup<Ts...> &&tup){
   return f(std::forward<Ts>(std::get<Ts>(tup))...);
}
```

but then it only works with rvalues

```
auto it = std::make_tuple(1,2);
cout << apply([](int a, int b){return a + b;},std::move(it)) << endl;
```

For lvalue references I get

```
error: no matching function for call to 'apply'
    cout << apply([](int a, int b){return a + b;},it) << endl;
            ^~~~~
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: It might not be the best example because I am using ints which will always be copied.

Comment: The original code you posted doesn't work. `std::get<Ts>` only works if each type in `Ts` is unique.

Comment: Most of the answers in the duplicate are obsolete. The most modern one I could find is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19060157/701092).

Comment: @0x499602D2 Haha, my current version looks almost the same. He just forwards the tuple into std::get where I forward outside of the std::get, not sure which one is right. I probably start another question.

Comment: You don't need to forward the result of `std::get`. That is done automatically. As for forwarding the tuple itself within expression the pack expansion appears, I believe that would be incorrect if `tup` referred to an rvalue as it would be moved more than once. So `get<Ts>(tup)` is the correct form.

Comment: @MaikKlein : He also takes the tuple as a forwarding reference where you don't. I.e., his use of `forward` is correct, yours is not. ;-]