# How can I find if an element exists in a tuple?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14

Suppose I have a `std::tuple`:

```
std::tuple<Types...> myTuple;
// fill myTuple with stuff
```

Now I want to find if `func` returns true for any element in the lambda, where `func` is some lambda, e.g.:

```
auto func = [](auto&& x) -> bool { return someOperation(x); }
```

How can I do this? Note that `Types...` may be large so I don't want to iterate over *all* elements every time.

Comment: You could [unpack the tuple for calling a variadic-template function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments) which check each argument.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple).

Comment: @m8mble I've added a line to highlight why this is different (basically it's the difference between `for_each` and `any_of` - stopping on the element when you find it).

Comment: Those don't seem like viable dupe targets. What do you want as a return type? A `variant`? `size_t` index?

Comment: @krzaq sorry, I realised my example was poorly worded - I'm actually after `any_of`. I hope this clears it up - the return type is `bool`.

Comment: `std::apply([](auto&&... args) { return (someOperation(decltype(args)(args)) || ...); }, myTuple);`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki what's the purpose of `decltype(args)` in this solution?

Comment: @krzaq the same as if I used `std::forward`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki okay, so it's a C function-style static cast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, char, double> myTuple{ 1, 'a', 3.14f };

bool result = std::apply([](auto&&... args) {
                           return (someOperation(decltype(args)(args)) || ...);
                         }
                       , myTuple);
```

[**DEMO**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GTb0CAixD1Iwr554)

Comment: in this case it can be just `args`, but in general, if, say, one would type `std::move(myTuple)` in `apply`, then I believe forwarding might be useful

Comment: I would mention that `std::apply` is C++17.

Comment: @skypjack so are fold expressions

Answer (score 2):

Here's a C++14 solution:

```
template <typename Tuple, typename Pred>
constexpr bool any_of_impl(Tuple const&, Pred&&, std::index_sequence<>) {
    return false;
}

template <typename Tuple, typename Pred, size_t first, size_t... is>
constexpr bool any_of_impl(Tuple const& t, Pred&& pred, std::index_sequence<first, is...>) {
    return pred(std::get<first>(t)) || any_of_impl(t, std::forward<Pred>(pred), std::index_sequence<is...>{});
}

template <typename... Elements, typename Pred, size_t... is>
constexpr bool any_of(std::tuple<Elements...> const& t, Pred&& pred) {
    return any_of_impl(t, std::forward<Pred>(pred), std::index_sequence_for<Elements...>{});
}
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/q5mQoMerkJTyKSv8)

Comment: good solution, yet I'm not sure if there is any compilation time boost from using `std::integer_sequence` as you instantiate `any_of_impl` for each index of tuple elements, no?

Comment: @W.F. I was about to reply that I need this because tuple may have duplicated types and `get<type>` wouldn't work, but with this recursive short-circuiting I don't need this. I'll update with a better version, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

And here's a little bit retro c++11 solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <class Tuple, class Lambda>
bool any_of(Tuple &&tup, Lambda lambda, std::integral_constant<size_t, std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value> i) {
    return false;
}

template <class Tuple, class Lambda, class I = std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>>
bool any_of(Tuple &&tup, Lambda lambda, I i = {}) {
    return lambda(std::forward<typename std::tuple_element<i, Tuple>::type>(std::get<i>(tup))) ||
           any_of(std::forward<Tuple>(tup), lambda, std::integral_constant<size_t, i+1>{});
}

int main() {
   std::cout << any_of(std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2, 3, 4), [](int&& i) { return i == 2; }) << std::endl;
}
```