# Variadic templates using std::function as parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, std-function

How can i simplify code below. Is it possibly to use here tuples? If yes, can u explain how.

```
template<typename Out, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
void ProcessIncomingCommand(PClientContext pClientContext,
    DWORD & bytesProcessed,
    const std::function<Out(T1, T2, T3, T4)> &function,
    const std::vector<UINT> &params);

template<typename Out, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
static void ProcessIncomingCommand(PClientContext pClientContext,
    DWORD & bytesProcessed,
    const std::function<Out(T1, T2, T3)> &function,
    const std::vector<UINT> &params);

template<typename Out, typename T1, typename T2>
static void ProcessIncomingCommand(PClientContext pClientContext,
    DWORD & bytesProcessed,
    const std::function<Out(T1, T2)> &function,
    const std::vector<UINT> &params);
```

In template implementation is needed to invoke function with parameters passed by `std::vector` of `UINT`. Parameters may differ, so it is required to cast them to proper types.

```
auto resFromFunction= function(params.at(0),
    params.at(1),
    static_cast<T3>(params.at(2)),
    static_cast<T4>(params.at(3)));
```

How can i use  [log0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323547/log0) answer here?

```
template<typename Out, typename... T>static void ProcessIncomingCommand(PClientContext pClientContext,
DWORD & bytesProcessed,
const std::function<Out(T...)> &function,
const std::vector<UINT> &params)
```

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do here? What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: What would the tuples be used to ?

Comment: In realisation i invoke function with parameters passed by vector of UINT. types in vector may differ from template  args (T...). I need to cast them to proper types. Ex: function(static_cast<T1>(params.at(0)),  ... ) etc. Is it proper way to use templates here?

Comment: Please specify, in the question post, what the parameters are supposed to do, how exactly you want it to be simplified, and try give a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure... but I suppose you need a function helper and `std::index_sequence` (or something similar).

A possible example

```
template <typename Out, typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
static Out PIC_helper (
   PClientContext pClientContext,
   DWORD & bytesProcessed,
   const std::function<Out(Ts...)> &function,
   const std::vector<UINT> &params,
   std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return function( static_cast<Ts>(params.at(Is))... ); }

template <typename Out, typename ... Ts>
static void ProcessIncomingCommand (
   PClientContext pClientContext,
   DWORD & bytesProcessed,
   const std::function<Out(Ts...)> &function,
   const std::vector<UINT> &params)
 {
   Out resFromFunction
      = PIC_helper(pClientContext, bytesProcessed, function, params,
                   std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());

   // other ...
 }
```

Observere that `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence()` are C++14 features; but if you need a C++11 solution, you can easily create something to substitute they.

Comment: I'l try to implement your solution and test it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Can you please fix return types of templates.

Comment: @SmitYcyken - sorry but I don't understand.

Comment: static void PIC_helper return type "Out" not a "void". ProcessIncomingCommand has no return value. Rest is ok. Please edit the post for other people who gonna have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles.

```
template<typename Out, typename... T>
static void ProcessIncomingCommand(PClientContext pClientContext,
    DWORD & bytesProcessed,
    const std::function<Out(T...)> &function,
    const T&... params) { function(params...); }

int main()
{
  PClientContext p;
  DWORD d = 0.5;
  std::function<int(double, int, char)> f;
  double a;
  int b;
  char c;
  ProcessIncomingCommand(p, d, f, a, b, c);
}
```

If you want to pass params as a tuple, it is going to be trickier:
See [How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments)
Except of course if you change `function` to take a tuple instead of a list of parameters...

Comment: How can i invoke function with N parameters? Please look at comment above for imformation about template implementation.

Comment: ok it was not clear for me that params were going to be passed to `function`. just edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something like

```
template<typename ResultType, std::size_t... I>
ResultType tuple_from_vector_impl(std::vector<UINT> params, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(static_cast<decltype(std::get<I>(std::declval<ResultType>()))>(params[I])...);
}

template<typename... Args, typename Indices = std::index_sequence_for<Args...>>
std::tuple<Args...> tuple_from_vector(std::vector<UINT> params)
{
    return tuple_from_vector_impl<std::tuple<Args...>>(params, Indices{});
}

template<typename Out, typename ... Args>
void ProcessIncomingCommand(PClientContext pClientContext,
                            DWORD & bytesProcessed,
                            const std::function<Out(Args...)> &function,
                            const std::vector<UINT> &params)
{
    // preamble
    std::tuple<Args...> args = tuple_from_vector<Args...>(params);
    Out result = std::apply(function, args);
    // postamble
}

template<typename ... Args>
void ProcessIncomingCommand(PClientContext pClientContext,
                            DWORD & bytesProcessed,
                            const std::function<void(Args...)> &function,
                            const std::vector<UINT> &params)
{
    // preamble
    std::tuple<Args...> args = tuple_from_vector<Args...>(params);
    std::apply(function, args);
    // postamble
}
```