# How to template Varaidic as return type in template?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I'm stuck with variadic template problem.

## Contexte

On one hand, I use a library whose functions look like

```
template<class ...Cols>
void doForVars(Cols&... args) {
   ...
}
```

And on the other hand I have a lot of structs

```
struct Foo {
    int id;
    std::string name;
    double length;
}

struct Bar {
    int id;
    double someProperty;
    double someOther;
}
```

I have for each of them to use a specialized template

```
template<>
void doSomething(Foo& foo) {
    //boilerplate 
    doForVars( foo.id, foo.name, foo.length); 
}


template<>
void doSomething(Bar& bar) {
    //boilerplate 
    doForVars( bar.id, bar.someProperty, bar.someOther); 
}
```

## Problem and expectations

As I get more than 50 types like `Foo` and `Bar` with 10 to 30 fields, there a lot of boilerplate to copy and paste.
It's error-prone and such a violation of DRY that I can stand for it :)

So, I'm searching for to create a template for a function `listFields(T& t)` that just *list* fields of record T and whose return value is acceptable for `doForVars(Cols...&cols)`.

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(T& t) {
    //boilerplate 
    doForVars(listFields(t)); 
}
```

But I don't succeed to write this template *returnint* a variadic type.

```
template<typename T, ?>
<I don't know> listFields(T& t);
```

such as I could just write

```
template<>
<I don't know> listFields(Foo& foo) {
    return <I don't know>( foo.id, foo.name, foo.length); 
}

template<>
<I don't know> listFields(Bar& bar) {
    return <I don't know>( bar.id, bar.someProperty, bar.someOther); 
}
```

variadic are shown as input, but how to use them for *output* ?

Thanks by advance.

## EDIT

Thank you for your answers I'm reading. As I wrote, I get a lot of record to describe and use ([SCOS 2000 MIB records types])[1](https://ccs.terma.com/resources/CCS_TER_ICD_001.pdf)

The library I use for variadic is this jewel https://github.com/d99kris/rapidcsv

I use it to parse some tabulation separated value files and map each row to my records. Pretty smooth.

Comment: Does `listFields` have to be a collection of template specializations, instead of an overload set?

Comment: Is there only one `doForVars` or do you want work with more of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valid for C++17.

What you want might get quite hard and I do not think there is a generic solution apart form using macros.

The first part is actually easy, you can use `std::tie` and simply return tuples.

```cpp
auto listFields(Foo& foo) {
    return std::tie( foo.id, foo.name, foo.length); 
}
```

I am generally against using template functions and full specialization together. Overloads can do most of the job already. Is there a reason for using them?

Thanks to `auto` return type and class template argument deduction, there is no need to write any types. I do not think there is a better solution, in C++ it is not possible to return multiple object through the return statement.

Now, about calling those library functions.

If `doForVars` is the only one you need to call, then the cleanest solution is probably based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37100646):

```cpp
template<typename T>
void call_doForVars(T& obj){
    std::apply([](auto &&... args) { doForVars(args...); }, listFields(obj));
}

int main(){
    Foo foo{1,"Quimby",176.5};
    call_doForVars(foo);
}
```

On the other hand, if you have more library functions, you hit a snag that it is AFAIK impossible to pass template function around and you need to pass it into an inner function because the arguments are one of the few places a parameter pack can be expanded. The lambda kinda bypasses this because it can create a function inside an expression.

My best advice so far in this case is to just wrap the previous solution into  a macro. You only need to do it once for each library function. (You can do it for `listFields` too, it will be cleaner).

## EDIT

I did find a solution for the generic case after all:

```cpp
template<typename...Args>
using fnc_t = void(*)(Args&... args);

auto listFields(Foo& foo) {
    return std::tie( foo.id, foo.name, foo.length); 
}
template<typename...Args>
void call(fnc_t<Args...> f, const std::tuple<Args&...>& t){
    std::apply(f, t);
}

int main(){
    Foo foo{1,"Quimby",176.5};
    call(doForVars, listFields(foo));
}
```

Was not that hard in the end, it only works with functions for now though.
One downside is that you have to call `listFields` in every call, which might be handy if your tuples come from other sources too. But if they don't, we can go one step further and get:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct helper{
using fnc_t = void;
};
template<typename...Args>
struct helper<std::tuple<Args&...>>{
using fnc_t = void(*)(Args&... args);
};
template<typename T>
using fnc_t2 = typename helper<decltype(listFields(std::declval<T&>()))>::fnc_t;

template<typename T>
void call2(fnc_t2<T> f, T& obj){
    std::apply(f, listFields(obj));
}
int main(){
    Foo foo{1,"Quimby",176.5};
    call2(doForVars, foo);
}
```

It's more mouthful, but `call2` can be hidden anyway and `call2(doForVars, foo);` is really nice result. :)

Here is a [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oa66v6).

Comment: Huh, looks like we hit upon the same idea at the same time :)

Comment: @cigien What do you mean at the same time? I posted it **one whole second** earlier ;)

Comment: Hah, I had to check. You're right, literally 1 second apart :D

Comment: This a perfect answer and solution for me. For template using, you're right, I maybe I tend to overuse: overload must be sufficient.

Comment: @MarcDeXeT Thanks, I did find a solution for the generic case of more library functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can't return multiple types from a function, even if it's a variadic template. However, you can return a `tuple` containing all the types that are members of a particular class. Also there seems to be no reason to write a template specialization for each of your `Foo`, `Bar`, etc. Instead, you can just add a function to the overload set for every type:

```
std::tuple<int, std::string, double> listFields(Foo& foo)
{
    return {foo.id, foo.name, foo.length};
}

std::tuple<int, double, double> listFields(Bar& bar)
{
    return {bar.id, bar.someProperty, bar.someOther};
}
```

Now since `doForVars` is a variadic template, you need to unpack the `tuple` returned form `listFields`, for which you can use `std::apply` like this:

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(T& t) {
    // ...
    std::apply([](auto &&... args) { doForVars(args...); }, listFields(t)); 
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h544E3)

Comment: Thank you ! Your demo works fine. As I'm a lazy guy, I'd like to avoid have to use tuple template.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can use `std::tuple`s, as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std::string_literals;

struct A{
    int int_a;
    double double_a;

    std::tuple<int&, double&> tuplize(){
        return {int_a, double_a};
    }

};

struct B{
    std::string str_b;
    bool bool_b;

    std::tuple<std::string&, bool&> tuplize(){
        return {str_b, bool_b};
    }
};

template <class ... Args>
void do_for_vars(Args& ... args){
    ((std::cout << args << ", "), ...);
    std::cout << "\n";
}
template <class ... Args>
void helper(std::tuple<Args...> t){
    std::apply(do_for_vars<Args...>, t);
}

int main(){
    A a{1, 1.4};
    B b{"str"s, true};
    helper(a.tuplize());
    helper(b.tuplize());

}
```

Comment: [`magic_get`](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) can even allow to have generic `tuplize`.

Comment: Why are you returning tuples of references btw?

Comment: @cigien because of this signature `void doForVars(Cols&... args)`

Comment: Ok, but I would change `helper` like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/on3b8W) instead.

Comment: Oh, wonderful magyc_get ! This is right I want to do ! I read the following answer to your suggestion.