# I can't pass template funtion to std::apply directly but I can through lambda

Tags: c++, templates, tuples

Based on: [How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments)

```cpp
#include <string>  
#include <iostream>    
#include <tuple>  

template <typename... Args>
void print_all(const Args &... args) {
    ((std::cout << " " << args), ...) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    // Create a tuple
    auto values = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3.4f, 4.5, "bob");
    
    // Need to pass the tuple through the lambda for template type deduction and to pass param to template function?
    std::apply([](auto &&... args) { print_all(args...); }, values);

    // This does not work - other then there is no parameter I can't see how this does not work
    // and how the lambda does work as it has the same (roughly) param list
    std::apply(print_all(), values);


    return 0;
}
```

can someone explain why one works and the other does not?

Comment: `print_all()` is a function call but you don't want to call the function - you want to pass it. It does work (with the right syntax): [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7be9b2eb49eb11e7). Though, type deduction doesn't seem to be an option here.

Comment: the pointers of these instances of a function template are different values, so compiler doesn't know what `print_all` should be decayed to. whether function template or overloaded function is not mono-state, you have to wrap it with a functor or a lambda, to give the argument a definite type.

Comment: @Scheff thnks for that - that makes sense to me, but (hopefully obviously) I don't want to pass all the template types! :)

Comment: @RedFog I think I get that bit - what I was struggling with is how the lambda works given it has the same param list -but as the answer below points out its more like an operator() template overload then a function template (If I understood correctly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behind the scences, this lambda expression `[](auto &&... args) { print_all(args...); }` is roughly of type:

```
 struct [unnamed] {
      template <typename ...Args>
      void operator()(Args&&...args) { ... };
 };
```

It is a type with a templated `operator()`, ie overload resolution and template argument dedcution only take place once the `operator()` is actually called. `print_all` on the other hand is a template, hence you cannot pass it to `std::apply`.

In other words, no matter what `Args...` is, the lambda is always of same type, but `print_all` isn't. You would need to instantiate it before you can get a pointer to the function. As mentioned by Scheff, this is fine:

```
std::apply(&print_all<int, int, float, double, const char*>, values);
```

Comment: oh I see.... so if I made a struct (like you did) with a template operator() then it will work - hence using a lambda is a nice trick to get around that - got you thanks!