# Expand tuple to parameters pack in member initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++17, iterable-unpacking, stdtuple

I need to initialize a base class with arguments stored in a std::tuple.
I have access to C++17 and managed to figure out that std::make_from_tuple may work but would require a copy constructor for the base class.

An example:

```
#include <tuple>

template<class Base>
class WithTupleConstructor : public Base // Sort of a Mixin class template
{
    public:

    // Creating a Base with arguments stored in tuple and then copying it
    template<class Tuple>
    WithTupleConstructor(const Tuple& base_args)
    : Base(std::make_from_tuple<Base>(base_args)) }
    { }
};

class WithCopyConstructor
{
    public:
    
    WithCopyConstructor(int a, int b)
    {};
    WithCopyConstructor(const WithCopyConstructor& other)
    {};
};

class WithoutCopyConstructor
{
    public:
    WithoutCopyConstructor(int a)
    {};
    WithoutCopyConstructor(const WithoutCopyConstructor& other) = delete;
};

int main()
{
  WithTupleConstructor<WithCopyConstructor> m1(std::make_tuple(1,2));

  // this do not compiles
  //WithTupleConstructor<WithoutCopyConstructor> m2(std::make_tuple(1));
}
```

std::make_index_sequence and std::get seem to demand an auxiliary function and cannot see how they could be used to solve this (as explained here [tuple-to-parameter-pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612596/tuple-to-parameter-pack)).

Is there a way to expand the tuple in the initialize list without requiring the copy constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution based in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65443996/8643925), turns out that it is achievable using `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::get`.

An auxiliary function that "unwraps" the tuple is required but it can be defined as a private constructor:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename Tuple>
using make_tuple_index_sequence = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>>;

template<class Base>
class WithTupleConstructor : public Base // Sort of a Mixin class template
{
    public:

    // Passing tuple and index sequence to auxiliary constructor
    template<class Tuple>
    WithTupleConstructor(const Tuple& base_args)
    : WithTupleConstructor(base_args, make_tuple_index_sequence<Tuple>{})
    {}

    private:

    // Expanding tuple using std::get
    template<class Tuple, std::size_t ...tuple_n>
    WithTupleConstructor(const Tuple& base_args, std::index_sequence<tuple_n...> )
    : Base(std::get<tuple_n>(base_args)...)
    {}
};

class WithCopyConstructor
{
    public:
    
    WithCopyConstructor(int a, int b)
    {}
    WithCopyConstructor(const WithCopyConstructor& other)
    {}
};

class WithoutCopyConstructor
{
    public:

    WithoutCopyConstructor(int a)
    {}
    WithoutCopyConstructor(const WithoutCopyConstructor& other) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    WithTupleConstructor<WithCopyConstructor> m1(std::make_tuple(1,2));

    WithTupleConstructor<WithoutCopyConstructor> m2(std::make_tuple(1));
}
```

This can be further extended to support rvalues and perfect forwarding by adding `&&` and `std::forward` when receiving and passing the tuples.

Comment: Beautiful solution.

Answer (score 0):

`std::make_from_tuple` will return a type `Base`, which will then be used by `Base`'s copy constructor to create `m1` or `m2`, as you mentioned.

I don't know if a different approach as the one I show below would fit you:

- `WithTupleConstructor` just forwards the tuple to `Base`.
- Each `Base` has a constructor receiving a specific tuple.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/zWhz34EEb)

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>  // forward

template<typename Base>
struct WithTupleConstructor : public Base {
    template<typename Tuple>
    WithTupleConstructor(Tuple&& base_args)
    : Base{ std::forward<Tuple>(base_args) }
    {}
};

struct WithCopyConstructor {
    int a_{};
    int b_{};

    WithCopyConstructor(std::tuple<int,int>&& t)
    : a_{std::move(std::get<0>(t))}, b_{std::move(std::get<1>(t))} {}
    WithCopyConstructor(int a, int b) {};
    WithCopyConstructor(const WithCopyConstructor& other) {};
};

struct WithoutCopyConstructor {
    int a_{};

    WithoutCopyConstructor(std::tuple<int>&& t)
    : a_{std::move(std::get<0>(t))} {}
    WithoutCopyConstructor(int a) {};
    WithoutCopyConstructor(const WithoutCopyConstructor& other) = delete;
};

int main() {
    WithTupleConstructor<WithCopyConstructor> m1(std::tuple{1,2});
    WithTupleConstructor<WithoutCopyConstructor> m2(std::tuple{1});

    fmt::print("m1: ({}, {})\n", m1.a_, m1.b_);
    fmt::print("m2: ({})\n", m2.a_);
}

// Outputs:
//
//   m1: (1, 2)
//   m2: (1)
```

Comment: The problem is in the context of a heavy generic programming framework and I don't really have access to the base classes. I'm trying not to add requirements on their constructors/interface.