# How to implement something like std::apply in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming, std, stdapply

Is there a way to implement `std::apply` in c++11?

I have a `std::tuple<Args...> myTuple` and a `std::function<void(const Args&...)> myFunction`

How can I invoke `myFunction` and pass it the contents of `myTuple` as arguments in C++11?

Comment: the possible implementation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) is a good start

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments

Comment: C++14 makes it easier and better compile time performance  C++11.

Comment: This page might have some information for you: [STL Algorithms on Tuples](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/03/08/stl-algorithms-on-tuples/)