# How can I determine parameters of lambda in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda

I want to transform all functions, which take tuples as arguments, passed to Foo into functions which take plain arguments.

```
auto f = [](const std::tuple<int, char>& t) { return std::get<0>(t); };

template <typename F>
auto Foo(F&& f) {
    ...
}

Foo(f)(42, 'a')
```

My idea was to do something like this

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
auto Foo(std::function<ReturnType(const std::tuple<Args...>&)> f) {
    return [&](Args&&... args) -> ReturnType {
      return f({std::forward<Args>(args)...});  
    };
}
```

But compiler couldn't infer template arguments for a lambda and ignored this candidate.

Comment: I think you need to use std::apply,   std::apply([](auto &&... args) { my_func(args...); }, my_tuple); (also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't really need the parameter types. simply

```
template <typename Callable>
auto Foo(Callable f) {
    return [=](auto&&... args)->decltype(auto){
      return f({std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...});
    };
}
```

---

the plus side is `Foo` can now accept more generic `f`, which could have multiple `opreator()` defined.

Comment: you may also add `mutable` if `f` has non-const `operator()`

Comment: or capture `f=std::move(f)` for non-copyable or heavy to copy ones.