# How to properly generically forward a parameter pack into a lambda?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, perfect-forwarding

I'm trying to forward a generic parameter pack from a base function, but trouble doing so, particularly if there are non-literal non-reference types in the type list

Considering the following example:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

template < typename... Args >
class BaseTemplate {
 public:
    BaseTemplate() = default;
    virtual ~BaseTemplate() = default;

    virtual std::future< void > call(Args... args) {
        return std::async(std::launch::async, [this, &args... ] {
            // ..
            first(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            second(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            third(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            // ...
        });
    }

 protected:
    virtual void first(Args...) { /* ... */ }
    virtual void second(Args...) = 0;
    virtual void third(Args...) { /* ... */ }
};


class SomeType {
 public:
    explicit SomeType(std::vector< float >* data) : ptr(data) { /* ... */ }
    ~SomeType() = default;
    // ...
    // protected:
    float member = 5.6;
    std::vector< float >* ptr;
};


class Derived1 : public BaseTemplate< int, float, SomeType > {
 public:
    using Base = BaseTemplate< int, float, SomeType >;

    Derived1() : Base() { /* ... */ }
    ~Derived1() = default;

 protected:
    void second(int, float, SomeType obj) override {
        std::cout << "Derived1::" << __func__ << " (" << obj.member << ")" << std::endl;
        printf("%p\n", obj.ptr);
        for (const auto& val : *(obj.ptr)) {
            std::cout << val << std::endl;
        }
    }
};


class Derived2 : public BaseTemplate< int, float, const SomeType& > {
 public:
    using Base = BaseTemplate< int, float, const SomeType& >;

    Derived2() : Base() { /* ... */ }
    ~Derived2() = default;

 protected:
    void second(int, float, const SomeType& obj) override {
        std::cout << "Derived2::" << __func__ << " (" << obj.member << ")" << std::endl;
        printf("%p\n", obj.ptr);
        for (const auto& val : *(obj.ptr)) {
            std::cout << val << std::endl;
        }
    }
};



int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::vector< float > data {0, 1, 2, 3};

    SomeType obj(&data);
    Derived1 foo1;
    Derived2 foo2;

    // auto bar1 = foo1.call(1, 5.6, obj);  // Segmentation fault
    auto bar2 = foo2.call(1, 5.6, obj);  // OK

    // ...

    // bar1.wait();
    bar2.wait();

    return 0;
}
```

Everything works as intended if `SomeType` is passed by reference, but *segfaults* if passed by value. What is the proper way to use `std::forward<>()` in order to account for both cases?

Comment: To make it easier for other people to help you, you should pare this down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, the `first` and `third` functions should be removed from the question since they are not relevant to the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: The issue is not with forwarding the arguments to `first` et al - it's with capturing them in the lambda. You always capture by reference; whenever the parameter is passed by value, the lambda ends up holding dangling references. Not just for `SomeType`, for `int` and `float` too; they just happen not to obviously crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with `std::forward` calls; the program exhibits undefined behavior before it gets to them. `call` takes some parameters by value, but the lambda inside always captures them by reference. Thus, it ends up holding references to local variables, which are destroyed as soon as `call` returns - but the lambda is called later, possibly on a different thread. At that point, all those references are dangling - not just the reference to `SomeType`, but also to `int` and to `float`.

---

One possible solution could go like this:

```
virtual std::future< void > call(Args... args) {
    std::tuple<BaseTemplate*, Args...> t{this, args...};
    return std::async(std::launch::async, [t] {
        // ..
        std::apply(&BaseTemplate::first, t);
        std::apply(&BaseTemplate::second, t);
        std::apply(&BaseTemplate::third, t);
        // ...
    });
}
```

We store arguments in a tuple - copies of those passed by value, references to those passed by reference. Then the lambda captures this tuple by value, and uses `std::apply` to pass its components along to the actual function being called.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eeo3Gaoqo)

Comment: It solves my issue, buta question regarding the solution anyway: you say *[...] the lambda inside [call()] always captures them by reference* but the tuple is itself captured by value - why though? What's the problem in capturing `args...` by value?

Comment: Well, `t` is itself a local variable. If I captured it by reference, I'd be right back where I started. So I copy the tuple - but, if any `Arg` is a reference type, then the tuple would store a reference for that component. That is, `t` is `std::tuple<int, float, SomeType>` for `Derived1`, but `std::tuple<int, float, const SomeType&>` for `Derived2`; it passes the reference along.

Comment: The problem with always capturing `args...` by value is that then even for `Derived2` you'd make a copy of `SomeType`. Which may not compile e.g. if `SomeType` is not copyable.

Comment: Also, I should have stated that in the question, but would prefer to stick to C++14 - are there any `std::apply` alternatives?

Comment: E.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments)

Comment: Also, and sorry for adding another comment, would there be any advantage in changing the signature of `call()` to take forwarding references i.e. `call(Args&&...)`?

Comment: They won't be forwarding references - not unless you change the design and make `call` a function template, rather than a non-template method on a class template. The whole point of perfect forwarding is that whether the parameter is taken by lvalue or rvalue reference is deduced from the function call - but in your design, it's baked into `BaseTemplate` instantiation.