# Convert tuple to variadic arguments

Tags: c++, generics, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm not sure what I want to achieve is possible, but I need my templated function (`my_func`) to be able to take both variable arguments as well as a tuple argument. Clearer description is in the code comments.

```
struct A{
    static void call_func(int a, std::string b) {
        std::cout<<"int is: "<<a<<", string is: "<<b<<"\n";
    }
};

struct B{
    static void call_func(std::string a, std::string b) {
        std::cout<<"string is: "<<a<<", string is: "<<b<<"\n";
    }
};

struct C{
    static void call_func(int a) {
        std::cout<<"int is: "<<a<<"\n";
    }
};

template<typename T, typename... Args> 
void my_func(Args... args) {
    T::call_func(args...);
}


int main() {

    my_func<A>(3, "ant");    //int is: 3, string is: ant
    my_func<B>("bat", "bee");  //string is: bat, string is: bee
    my_func<C>(5);  //int is: 5


    //Is there a way to call(or modify) my_func such that it also accepts a tuple
    std::tuple<int, std::string> a_params{3,"tuple-ant"};
    std::tuple<std::string, std::string> b_params{"tuple-bat","tuple-bee"};
    std::tuple<int> c_params{7};
    // my_func<A>(a_params); 
    // my_func<B>(b_params);
    // my_func<C>(c_params);   
 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what are the results?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure it's a good idea that both functions are called `my_func()`? To avoid confusion, what about `my_func_tuple()`, or something similar, for the second one?

Anyway... it seems to me that you're looking for `std::apply()`; with it the tuple version can be written as

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
void my_func(std::tuple<Args...> tpl) {
  std::apply(T::call_func, tpl);
}
```

Take in count that `std::apply()` is available starting from C++17; before C++17 (C++11 and C++14) you have to simulate it using a integer sequence; see the Mooing Duck answer for a good example.

Comment: lol I forgot about `std::apply`

Comment: @MooingDuck - Great addition to the language, `std::apply()`. Unfortunately, I tend to forget it.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost exactly what `integer_sequence` was made for:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args, std::size_t... ints> 
void my_func(std::tuple<Args...> args, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t,ints...> sequence) {
    T::call_func(std::get<ints>(args)...);
}
```

`std::get<ints>(args)...` says for each item in the `size_t...ints` template parameter, call `get<ints>(args)`. This lets you unpack args as a list of parameters to the method. But then we have to figure out how to make the right `integer_sequence`. Luckily, that's also easy:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args> 
void my_func(std::tuple<Args...> args){
    my_func<T, Args...>(args, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{});
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1dfdb24d5d21c756

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `std::apply` and are using c++20, you can just do this:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename...Args>
void my_func(std::tuple<Args...>& args) {
    [&] <std::size_t...Is> (std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        T::call_func(std::get<Is>(args)...);
    } (std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{});
}
```

It uses the lambda to expand the index sequence, allowing you to access each member, and call `call_func` with them.

Still, `std::apply` is probably the best choice for this.