# type deducing only the arguments types for a variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, apply, variadic-templates, type-deduction

I am trying to apply a variadic template function to a tuple. I found following solution that works for C++14 (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37100646/2712726).

```
#include <tuple>
template <typename T, typename U> void my_func(T &&t, U &&u) {}
int main(int argc, char *argv[argc]) {
  std::tuple<int, float> my_tuple;
  std::apply([](auto &&... args) { my_func(args...); }, my_tuple);
  return 0;
}
```

I also found many solutions for C++11 but non of those compiled. So I implemented my own solution, which also does not compile.

Following code shows my attempt. My question is why type deduction in the last statement `u.apply(f)` fails and if I can help the compiler somehow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

template <typename... T>
struct parameter_pack : public parameter_pack<T>... {
    parameter_pack(const T&... t) : parameter_pack<T>(t)... {}

    // C++11
    template <template <typename...> class Func>
    void apply(Func<T...> f) {
        f(parameter_pack<T>::h...);
    }
    //c++14 works
    // template <typename Func>
    // void apply(Func f) {
    //     f(parameter_pack<T>::h...);
    // }

    // UPDATE:
    // This solution from Holy Black Cat Works great with C++11 too
    //void apply(void (*f)(const T&...)) {
    //    f(parameter_pack<T>::h...);
    //}
};

template <typename H>
struct parameter_pack<H> {
    parameter_pack(const H& h) : h(h) {}
    const H& h;
};

template <typename... T>
parameter_pack<T...> make_parameter_pack(const T&... t) {
    return parameter_pack<T...>(t...);
}

// test function f()
template <typename H>
void f(const H& h) {
    std::cout << h << std::endl;
}

template <typename H, typename... T>
void f(const H& h, const T&... t) {
    f(h);
    f(t...);
}

int main() {
    auto u = make_parameter_pack(1, 1.1, "hello");
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // C++11
    u.apply(f); // compiler error

    //C++14 works
    // auto lambda = [&](const auto&... args) {
    //    f(args...);
    // };
    // u.apply(lambda);
}
```

The compiler says:

```
<source>:49:7: error: no matching member function for call to 'apply'
   49 |     u.apply(f);
      |     ~~^~~~~
<source>:12:10: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'Func'
   12 |     void apply(Func<T...> f) {
      |          ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

**UPDATE**
I have added Holy Cat's solution and marked as UPDATE in the code. That works.

Comment: 1. `std::apply` is C++17, not C++14. 2. Why are you reinventing `std::tuple`, instead of just writing your own replacement for `std::apply` that accepts `std::tuple`? Your version won't work with single element packs, or with packs with non-unique types.

Comment: `Func<T...> f` doesn't work because the type of `f` or of `f<....>` isn't a specialization of some template, it's just `void(/*something*/)`. The only sane option is to make the function a member of a struct, and pass the whole struct (imitate what C++14 generic lambdas are doing).

Comment: implementing my own `std::apply` will not be good enough because that cannot apply functions with variadic template arguments, hence the need for `[](auto&&...args){...}` which only exists since C++14.

Comment: This doesn't explain reimplementing `std::tuple`, whatever solution you end up with can accept `std::tuple`. Accepting a variadic function directly isn't viable (I think it's possible, but you'll need to know the exact type, meaning no implicit conversions of the arguments, must know the return type in advance, etc). It's better to accept functor classes.

Comment: the purpose of my own tuple was to be able to have a non templated apply function. My idea was that this would enable type deduction. But, wrong idea 8-(. I think my mistake is that during type deduction in my apply method a partially specialized overload of function f would exist and that is not possible. Only classes can be partially specialized.

Comment: Wdym "non templated"? Your `apply` is a template.

Comment: Forgot , yes, not template argument but template template argument `Func<T...>` but T... is predetermined as this is the argument from the class itself. So, my idea was that `Func `is replaced with `f` and `T...` is used as template arguments of `f`. And you are correct, this would work if f was a class and not a function.

Comment: You probably meant `void apply(void (*f)(const T &...)) {f(parameter_pack<T>::h...);}`, which works for your code as is, but quickly breaks if the function e.g. accepts the parameter by value, or returns something other than void. That's why I'm saying it's not viable.

Comment: Oh, of course, this answers my question!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f` is a function template, and you can't take an address of a "blueprint for functions". You could take the address of, let's say, `f<int>` but not of `f`.

Why does it work with a lambda? Because lambdas are just syntactic sugar for callable structs: you'd be passing an object which exists and lives somewhere in memory, the fact that the call operator is a template has no impact. Were you to pass `lambda::operator()` or any variation of that, you'd come back to the same problem as above.